# Installing mod_wsgi-3.4 to go with python 3.4

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to run a flask app on an apache server so I am using mod_wsgi to deploy it. I downloaded python 3.4 from source and compiled it and it runs just fine. Now I did this:

```
cd
wget http://modwsgi.googlecode.com/files/mod_wsgi-3.4.tar.gz
tar -zxf mod_wsgi-3.4.tar.gz
cd mod_wsgi-3.4
sudo ./configure --with-python=/usr/local/opt/python-3.4.1/bin/python3.4

make
```

But when I run make I get this error chain:

```
/usr/bin/apxs2 -c -I/usr/local/opt/python-3.4.1/include/python3.4m -DNDEBUG   mod_wsgi.c -L/usr/local/opt/python-3.4.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/python-3.4.1/lib/python3.4/config  -lpython3.4 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
Use of uninitialized value $includedir in concatenation (.) or string at (eval 9) line 1.
/usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile --tag=disable-static x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -prefer-pic -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/openssl -I/usr/include/xmltok -pthread  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -I -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/apr-1.0     -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1.0   -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/opt/python-3.4.1/include/python3.4m -DNDEBUG  -c -o mod_wsgi.lo mod_wsgi.c && touch mod_wsgi.slo
/usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool --silent --mode=link --tag=disable-static x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro   -o mod_wsgi.la  -rpath /usr/lib/apache2/modules -module -avoid-version    mod_wsgi.lo -L/usr/local/opt/python-3.4.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/python-3.4.1/lib/python3.4/config -lpython3.4 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.4
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

And I just don't know what to make of it. And ideas?

Comment: The author recommends you use version 3.5 (https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) ...did you try that?

Comment: good idea I'd forgotten about that but actually I needed to recompile my python version with --enable-shared as an option when I did the ./configure as outlined here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/zk28E_XS68w